# how to have new line/multi-line input in flask-WTF & wtforms' string field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

In Flask wtform's StringField which handles multiline text input, I could only have a long string of text, even through I need to put in multiple lines. If the original text I pasted in has multiple lines, it became a long one-line string as well.

Pressing enter in the text area (string field) does not create a new line, instead it confirms the input. How can I break up a chunk of text into multiple lines in StringField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the `TextAreaField` field (`from wtforms import TextAreaField`), or change the widget for the `StringField` to a textarea:

```
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea

my_field = StringField('My Field', widget=TextArea())
```

In any case, you can also pass `rows` and `cols` parameters in your template:

```
{{ form.my_field(cols=50, rows=10) }}
```

Comment: for some reason the second method doesn't work, but the first method works well